# CSS shape with text inside

Tags: html, css

I need help.  So far I was able to create the left div, but I am stuck with the second div, the one from the right. Any tips please?

[Css Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxzTU.jpg)

```
This is the HTML

<div class="shape">
  ALEGETI MEDIEREA
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS

```
      .shape{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#8ed7c2;
  width:50%;
  height:178px;
  line-height:178px;
  color:#fef5ca;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  font-size:50px;
  top:20px;


}
.shape:after{
  content:"";
  width:0px;
  height:178px;
  border-top:178px solid rgba(3,78,136,0.7);
  border-right:60px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
   left:100%;


}
```

Comment: @mihal We could be helpful if you share some HTML and css as well, just be looking at the image it would be difficult to identify and fix it.

Comment: Post your code with the question. State what exactly you are trying to do and what you have done so far.

Comment: @mihal Not sure if you have shared the correct image (css shape), It has image in the background and your css doesn't have a reference.

Comment: I sliced that picture from a psd...the background color doesn t matter. I just need to align  those 2 pieces of text

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the HTML

<div class="shape">
  ALEGETI MEDIEREA
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS

```
      .shape{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#8ed7c2;
  width:50%;
  height:178px;
  line-height:178px;
  color:#fef5ca;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  font-size:50px;
  top:20px;


}
.shape:after{
  content:"";
  width:0px;
  height:178px;
  border-top:178px solid rgba(3,78,136,0.7);
  border-right:60px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
   left:100%;


}
```